# error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core-webapi, typescript-typings

I'm loading nested object but the data coming in does'nt have the correct closing for json "[":
Can someone help, I can't be able to retrieve the data.

> [{"Id":1,"Barcode":"N001",.....,"ProductSubCategoryID":1,"SellerId":0,"SellerName":null,"ProductSubCategory":{"ProductSubCategoryID":1,"SubCategoryName":"Lotion","Products":["

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    .
    .
    [ForeignKey("ProductSubCategoryID")]
    public virtual ProductSubCategory ProductSubCategory { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSubCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductSubCategoryID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(100)")]
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
    // GET: api/Product
    public async Task<Object> GetProducts()
    {
        return Ok(await _context.Products.Include(p => p.ProductSubCategory).ToListAsync());
    }
```

<---- Angular Code ---->

```
readonly BaseURI = 'http://localhost:54277/api/Product';

  private   product$: Observable<Product[]>;

  // Get All Products
  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    if (!this.product$) {
      this.product$ = this.http.get < Product[] > (this.BaseURI + '/GetProducts').pipe(shareReplay());
    }
    return this.product$;
  }
```

Comment: You should try to print the data. The error message is saying that your data does not have a correct JSON format and could not be parsed. You may validate your input here : https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in serialization. due to circular reference, ASP.Net Core is not able to serialize to JSON correctly. Product has the property of type ProductSubCategory and again ProductSubCategory has the property of type Product which causes a circular reference.

So ProductABC has ProductSubCategoryABC which again has a collection of product and has ProductABC.

To avoid circular reference modify your `startup.cs` and specify  `options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`

```cs
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it by simply adding a

```
{ get; set; }
```

to each property in my class, which is to be converted to a JSON object ;)